# pull data from one view to the other one in infopath

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have infopath which have multiple views and I am trying to pull data from one view to the other one and I have tried web services submit to get the data to populate to from other view but no luck but if you have in direction that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls bound to the same fields.

For instance, you have a field in your main data source called "ID" - you can have as many controls as you like bound to that field, in as many views as you need. And when the value is updated, all the controls will show the correct value.

In your second view, just look for the field in the data source task pane, and drag it onto the form then preview.

Answer (score 0):

Views in Infopath are not separate. View is only a way of showing underlying data. All data fields are available for functions in each view. So you can just set up value of Filed B in View B to Field A in view A if that is what you want. Moreover you can use functions if you want to concatenate of do some calculation before applying value to field B.